# Is the following even possible in android/windows phone/symbian?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, symbian

I don't have any knowledge about development on mobile platforms but me n friends are thinking of developing a mobile app(and in process earn fluency on mobile app development). It's related to the good old SMS service.

While receiving smses instead of storing them in inbox can we store them in different folders based on the various attributes of the message for eg. mobile no.(don't know much about what extra info. a message carries).The folders will be accessible through the app. only which may use encryption/related techniques to store messages.The idea is based on the fact that some messages are private, some are business related etc.

In fact we may loosely compare it to MS Outlook functionality for smses.The app's service keeps running and as soon as soon a sms is received it is picked up and stored in the appropriate folder.

I haven't used a smartphone therefore I thought it would be better to write to you guys.So is something like that possible on windows phone 7 or android or EDIT::symbian??

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to the history/sms/incoming calls from an app on a windows phone 7. You can receive and collect sms on Android `BroadcastReceiver`, but I am not sure if you can stop the default sms app from saving it in the sms log.

Comment: I don't want to stop the default service.My app will wait and watch for some kind of 'sms received event' and as soon as the sms is received the app will remove it from the default inbox and place it somewhere else.

Comment: Removing it from the default inbox is something uncertain, you'll have to see the documentation for that. Otherwise, yes most of your app's requirements should be satisfied by Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not possible for Windows Phone. As for Android, it's probably doable, but doesn't seem like a sane project.

Comment: I have a scenario to support my case:Suppose a friend/colleague of mine borrows my 'smartphone' to play a quick game or something else.But he can also peek at my personal messages right??

Comment: Indeed he can. Nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Symbian. You can create new folders into existing Messaging app under "My folders" folder - so you don't even have to store them separately. Catch the incoming SMS, read the sender phone and message and decide into witch folder it goes. If your app is not running then all SMSs remain in Inbox.